# channel or mutablesharedflow , which one is a better replacement for deprecated localbroadcastmanager

Tags: android, kotlin, channel, kotlin-sharedflow

In the past, I was using `LocalBroadcastManager and EventBus` in my chat and taxicab applications which are now either deprecated or not recommended using them.

I intend to replace them with new data structures like `mutablesharedflow or channel`,
i want to know which one is better matched with my case? or maybe another data structure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Roman Elizarov](https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c), Channels were added as an inter-coroutine communication primitive.

> You cannot use channels to distribute events or state updates in a way that allows multiple subscribers to independently receive and react upon them.

So they introduced `Flow`. But Flow is a cold observable, where every subscriber gets their own data (independent from other subscribers). With [SharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) you get a hot observable that emits independently of having any subscriber(s).

You could do the same with [ConflatedBroadcastChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/). But **JetBrains recommend to use Flow in favor of Channels because of their simpler API.**

So if you want to migrate to Coroutines and you need a hot observable multiple subscribers can listen to, you should go with `SharedFlow`.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, it is very helpful. i actually forgot to take MutableStateFlow into account, i'd like to know your opinion between StateFlow and SharedFlow in this scenario?

Comment: You are welcome. A StateFlow extends the SharedFlow. It is the same, but with a cached `value` property. So you can get it's latest state at any time, even outside the flow observation like `yourStateFlow.value`. So If you not just want to notify, but also allow others to ask the flows current state/value you should use `StateFlow`.

Comment: Note: `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` is obsolete since 1.5.0. It will be deprecated with warning in 1.6.0 and with error in 1.7.0. It is replaced with `StateFlow`. So from now on, should avoid using it. If you want to have multiple subscibers to subscribe to the same event use `SharedFlow`.

Answer (score -9):

Both are good for listening one time events. Everything depends in your use cases.

**SharedFlow** known as `hot flow` ->

1. Emit events even if no observer is listening to it
2. If no observer is listening to it, you loose these events

**Channels** known as `cold flow`

1. Does not emit events when no observer is not listening to it. It works like a BlockingQueue.
2. When you start to collect, it collects all data which were sent.

Comment: This is incorrect. Channels are hot, not cold. Channel consumes resources until closed.

Comment: Channel is hot and SharedFlow is cold.

Comment: @TarifChakder Both are hot, from the official site: "A shared flow is called hot because its active instance exists independently of the presence of collectors. "